# One <div> is wider than the others

Tags: html, css

So on a website I'm making a have a navigation bar, I use this code for it.

```
    <div id="container">
        <a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a>
        <a href="blackmail.html"><span>Blackmail</span></a>
        <a href="keep_safe.html"><span style="color: #7CFC00">Keeping Safe</span></a>
        <a href="bully.html"><span>Cyberbullying</span></a> 
            <a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a>
    </div>
```

However this navigation bar is wider than the others, exact same code (Apart from the colour, the colour shows what page you are on)
I would appreciate it if someone told me why this happens or how it could get fixed!

Website - nibble90.github.io

The page with the wider navigation bar is the keeping safe page!

Comment: can you set a snippet that shows your issue ? cause here : https://jsfiddle.net/cmzkk8qv/ nothing looks wrong

Comment: could you post the CSS relating to the issue? Or are you able to reproduce the issue in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I only see one nav bar on that webpage

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle, it doesn't really do it justice but here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/_Stamp_/mxa4y9ad/

Comment: Yeah, there's only suppose to be 1 nav bar however its longer than the rest on my website. If possible it would be cool if it was the same size as the banner thing at the top!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #container menu has a fixed width (83em) and a padding. When your content is longer than the page height, it causes a vertical scroll bar to appear and your fixed width elements can't adjust to accommodate it.

You should set its width to be 100% with a min-width of something like 550px and its sizing to be border-box. This will mean it fits your page much more gracefully on different sized browsers and also auto-adjust to the presence or absence of the vertical scroll bar.

So:

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    min-width:500px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `#container` code by this one and it will works. It's better to use `%` or `px` instead of `em` for container width.

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 25em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The width in your CSS is what is throwing you off. Remove the width and the divs will match in size.

```
#container {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px 0px;
margin-top: 2em;
text-align: center;
background-color: #333;
}
```

Make sure to remove both because you had width in there twice.